# Equivalence relation given B contained in A

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations

[image]

I have checked and shown that R is an equivalence relation. However, I am not quite sure how to go about part b.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Check to show that that for every $C\subseteq A$ there is at least one $B'$ such that $B'\subseteq B$ and $(C,B')\in\mathcal{R}$.  Hint: what is the relevance of $C\cap B$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For any $C\in\mathcal P(A)$, one has $C=(C\cap B)\cup(C\smallsetminus B)$.